# Bus error with long running "cp" command

Tags: hardware, memory

I'm copying about 800Gb of data between a samba share and a local usb attached ext4 hard drive. I'm about halfway through, and I've noticed that after a couple of hours of copying any command that I run results in (for `ls`):

```
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
Bus error
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870353/bus-error-system-error) talks about the hardware being unable to address memory anymore, and [this Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/What-does-Bus-error-mean-in-Linux-command-line) also points out that the issue is related to memory being unavailable. However, there isn't any good advice on how to fix/avoid the issue, or whether it is symptomatic of a more broader underlying problem.

The first time it happened I rebooted the Pi in question and restarted the copy (with no-clobber `-n` switch), and the system went back to normal for a few hours. Now I'm getting the same issue again. Is anyone else experiencing this, and is there any advice for avoiding/fixing?

**Edit**

The Pi is attached to a 1.2A capable wall plug, external HDD is independently powered and is connected to the Pi by a powered USB hub.

Comment: what's your power source for Raspi and local usb attached HDD ?

Comment: When copying large amounts of data I prefer to use `rsync`, as it can resume transfers, if something goes wrong. Not sure if this would fix your problem though.

Comment: anything strange in output of `dmesg` command?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski I'm not really familiar with dmesg, is there anything in particular I should look for? Nothing is jumping out at me, but does dmesg persist its messages across reboots?

Comment: @mrmagooey: We are looking for some network related errors, and something from CIFS filesystem or USB subsystem. Dmesg message does not persist across reboots.

Comment: All usb messages appear to be normal (e.g. hub found, device found). I don't think I can run dmesg whilst the problem is actually occurring because no binaries can be accessed.

Comment: I have the same problem:<br>
I am copying from samba to the SD card, and after about 800MB copied:<br>
+ cp -fr /mnt/samba/data .<br>
/tmp/hudson2766859438495729770.sh: line 91: 3972 Bus error cp -fr $DATATOPACK .<br> It looks like the filesystem gets corrupted as any subsequent call to any command returns: Input/output error<br>
++ date +%s<br>
/tmp/hudson2766859438495729770.sh: line 61: /bin/date: Input/output error<br>

Answer (score 1):

The rpi can be iffy under high cpu load. use nice and rsync with a bandwidth limit. Update to the latest firmware. 15TB sync no problem.